# equality of partial derivative to inner product divided by norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

For the question highlighted below, I've played around with the right side of the equality but am not sure how to express the left side in order to prove the equality.  My hunch was to express the left side as $\dfrac{y}{|y|}$, but then the right side would be $\dfrac{x_1y_1+...+x_ny_n}{\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}}$, so I don't see how equality would hold.

Thanks in advance

> Let $f(x)=|x|$, $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$.  Show that if $x,y\neq 0$, then $$D_y f(x)=\dfrac{\langle x,y \rangle}{|x|}$$

Comment: For starters, what is $D_yf(x)$ in this situation? What does it mean?

Comment: It is probably the derivative in the y direction

Comment: @ZachBoyd Yes, this is what it means.